# Displaying ui-grid correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm new to Angular.js and I'm working on a project which requires to use grid. I am trying to use ui-grid but I can't display the grid correctly.

[image]

I followed [this plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zm2snCK2A7GkEXXmWvZc?p=preview).

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Hello, single backticks can be used for one line of code. To create a code block you can highlight text and press ctrl+k or click the button with `{}` inside the editor. I added the picture for you. You will be able to add pictures with more reputation.